# spring-integration-aws: Setting the s3 retry

Tags: spring, amazon-s3, spring-integration

Is it possible out of the box to set the s3 retry setting on the `S3MessageHandler`, using the spring-integration-aws?

I am unable to see any other options:

```
 S3MessageHandler s3MessageHandler = new S3MessageHandler(amazonS3, PARSER.parseExpression("test"));
      s3MessageHandler.setCommandExpression(PARSER.parseExpression("headers.command"));
      s3MessageHandler.setSendTimeout(2000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS S3 retry options go outside of Spring Integration responsibility.

You see, the `S3MessageHandler` accepts `AmazonS3` instance. And already there you can configure `ClientConfiguration` with desired `RetryPolicy`.

Nevertheless Spring Integration provides its own `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` based on the Spring Retry project to be configure for the `S3MessageHandler` via `@ServiceActivator(adviceChain)`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.8.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain

Comment: Will you have a release of https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws any time soon?

Comment: We can make a milestone the next week. Does it work for you?

Comment: That's perfect we are looking forward to the next release. I will keep an eye out for it.